# Paw-app Checkbox Dynamic value always returns false

Tags: checkbox, paw-app

I'm using the JsonWebTokenDynamicValue extension
https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-JsonWebTokenDynamicValue

When I first installed/used the extension with the *Add Time Fields* checkbox checked, everything worked as expected.
Now (possibly after the first restart of the app?), checking the checkbox field appears to do nothing. It is always evaluating to false.

I went to the effort of downloading the source and adding some logging to verify what I was seeing.
Screenshot showing the box checked and the resulting value still being false 
[image: Screenshot showing the box checked and the resulting value still being false]

The other checkbox on this extension *Secret is Base64* is also misbehaving in the same way (always false).

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, the new update broke the checkboxes in JS extensions, we'll try to fix it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paw 3.0.9 update fixed this issue.
https://paw.cloud/updates/3.0.9